# creating DataFrame from a Data Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, data-analysis

I have a data series,

```
df,
           primary
Buy        484
Sell       429
Blanks     130
FX Spot    108
Income     77
FX Forward 2
```

trying to crate a dataframe with 2 column.
first column values should be the index of df
second column should have the values of primary in df

```
 by using,
 filter_df=pd.DataFrame({'contents':df.index, 'values':df.values})
 I get,
 Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for new column name:

```
filter_df = df.rename_axis('content').reset_index()
```

Another solution with `rename`:

```
filter_df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'content'})
```

For DataFrame from constructor need `df['primary']` for select column

```
filter_df=pd.DataFrame({'contents':df.index, 'values':df['primary'].values})
```

---

```
print (filter_df)
      content  primary
0         Buy      484
1        Sell      429
2      Blanks      130
3     FX Spot      108
4      Income       77
5  FX Forward        2
```